# Python: Divide one list by length of another and create a dictionary with that division

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists that change dynamically and I need to end up with a dictionary that divides the list evenly as they change in length and place the results into a dictionary.

```
Examples:
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']
Result:
c = { a:['x','y','z'], b:['l','m','n'], c:['p','q'] }

a = ['a','b']
b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']
Result:
c = { a:['x','y','z','l'], b:['m','n','p','q'] }

a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']
Result:
c = { a:['x','y'], b:['z','l'], c:['m','n'], d:['p','q'] }

a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q','r','t','s']
Result:
c = { a:['x','y','z','l'], b:['m','n','p','q'], c:['r','t','s'] }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I tried lots of different snippets of code but was not able to produce the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create chunks and map them with elements in `a`:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q','r','t','s']

import math

# find the size
size = math.ceil(len(b)/len(a))

# creating list of chunks of size 
chunks = [b[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(b), size)]

# matching chunks with elements in 'a'
c = {a[i]:chunks[i] for i in range(len(a))}
```

Alternatively, above steps can be done as using `dictionary comprehension`:

```
c = {a[index]:item for index, item in enumerate(b[i:i + size] 
                       for i in range(0, len(b), size))}
print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'l'], 'b': ['m', 'n', 'p', 'q'], 'c': ['r', 't', 's']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression:

```
def group_list(a,b):
    nl = (len(b)+len(a)-1)//len(a)
    return {a[i]:b[nl*i:nl*i+nl] for i in range(len(a))}
```

In case the number of items in `b` is not divisable by `b`, it will simply reduce the number of the *last* key.

This generates:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']
>>> group_list(a,b)
{'c': ['p', 'q'], 'a': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'b': ['l', 'm', 'n']}
>>> a = ['a','b']
>>> b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']
>>> group_list(a,b)
{'a': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'l'], 'b': ['m', 'n', 'p', 'q']}
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']
>>> group_list(a,b)
{'d': ['p', 'q'], 'c': ['m', 'n'], 'b': ['z', 'l'], 'a': ['x', 'y']}
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q','r','t','s']
>>> group_list(a,b)
{'c': ['r', 't', 's'], 'b': ['m', 'n', 'p', 'q'], 'a': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'l']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy makes quick work of this:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']
>>> dict(zip(a, map(list, np.array_split(b, len(a)))))
{'a': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'b': ['l', 'm', 'n'], 'c': ['p', 'q']}
```

In case the number of items in `b` is not divisible by `b`, it will distribute the items as evenly as possible:

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> b = range(10)
>>> dict(zip(a, map(list, np.array_split(b, len(a)))))
{'a': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `b` is a generator of unknown length, then you can use a succession of deques to build up the strings:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['x','y','z','l','m','n','p','q']

from collections import deque

results = [deque() for item in a]

for item in b:
    results[0].append(item)
    for d,d1 in zip(results, results[1:]):
        if len(d1) < len(d):
            d1.append(d.popleft())

dd = dict(zip(a, map(list, reversed(results))))
print(b)
for k in sorted(dd):
    print(k, dd[k])
```

Prints:

```
['x', 'y', 'z', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q']
a ['x', 'y', 'z']
b ['l', 'm', 'n']
c ['p', 'q']
```

Not sure if this will always give the desired groupings, but has the advantage of working with generators for `b` (never calls `len` on `a` or `b`).